# How to handle exception in AWS Lambda in C# for reprocessing

Tags: c#, .net, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb

I am a beginner in AWS and at present, I am sending data from DyanmoDB leveraging on [TTL](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/TTL.html) to AWS Lambda and then to an End Point. My manager wants me to handle a situation where Lambda throws some exception thus fails to deliver the events to an endpoint.

In case of exception from Lambda he wants me to send the entry back to the DynamoDB table. I am sure it should be doable by using `Put-Item` command. But I want to know is there any out of the box solution that Lambda provides with which I can handle the failure condition and reprocess that received event data, and thus not **lose the entries from DyanmoDB Stream** during an exception. By doing this I won't have to send the data back to DynamoDB.

Below is working code for AWS Lambda

```
public class Function

    {
        private JsonSerializer _jsonSerializer = new JsonSerializer();
        private readonly IQueueClient client;

        public async Task FunctionHandler(DynamoDBEvent dynamoEvent, ILambdaContext context)
        {
            try
            {
                foreach (var record in dynamoEvent.Records)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        if (record.EventName == OperationType.REMOVE)
                        {
                            context.Logger.LogLine("Calling SerializeStreamRecord function");
                            string streamRecordJson = SerializeStreamRecord(record.Dynamodb);
                            Debug.Write(streamRecordJson);
                            await SendAsync(streamRecordJson, context);
                            context.Logger.LogLine("Data Sent");
                        }
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        throw ex;
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                context.Logger.LogLine("Exception Occurred" + ex.Message);
            }

            context.Logger.LogLine("Stream processing complete.");
        }

        private async Task SendAsync(string stream, ILambdaContext context)
        {
            try
            {
                var message = new Message(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(stream));
                await client.SendAsync(message); // SEND MESSAGE
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw ex;
            }

        }

        private string SerializeStreamRecord(StreamRecord streamRecord)
        {
            try
            {
                using (var writer = new StringWriter())
                {
                    _jsonSerializer.Serialize(writer, streamRecord);
                    return writer.ToString();
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw ex;
            }

        }
    }
```